# Mining with one GPU

Tags: miner-configuration, gpu-mining

How do I GPU mine with only one GPU, which I'm currently using for graphics? Does that require going headless? How do I go headless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend first checking this list to see what your expected hash rate will be:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison

And then see how much you will make from that rate:

http://www.alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator

Please factor in power consumption. After you have made a decision to mine armed with those facts, I'd join a mining pool and download GuiMiner.

http://guiminer.org/

http://mining.bitcoin.cz/

The pool operator will be happy to address your questions on how to setup the mining client as you are making them money.

Comment: I'm aware of GPUs' limitations for mining; I'm only doing this for testing purposes. thanks for the links, though

Comment: head over to bitcointalk.org and ask around. It sounds like you need a discussion to answer your question. The mining community there is second to none